# Define (and declare and use) global variables from function through macros

Tags: c++, scope, macros, pthreads, global-variables

I’m trying to reimplement in a backward-compatible way the RobotC API from C (although some details such as automatical inclusion of stdbool, optional parameters, references, I/O through “array”/subscript notation value/assignment, etc. would better fit C++ and some issues may be easier to solve in C++…). This one includes [`void startTask(void TaskID, short nTaskPriority)`](http://help.robotc.net/WebHelpMindstorms/index.htm#Resources/topics/LEGO_EV3/ROBOTC/Task_Control/startTask.htm) and [`void stopTask(void TaskID)`](http://help.robotc.net/WebHelpMindstorms/index.htm#Resources/topics/LEGO_EV3/ROBOTC/Task_Control/stopTask.htm) to enable multithreading.

TaskID is meant to *directly be* the name of the function to run in a new thread. So no thread number variable there, only the global-scope function name. I first tried to implement something near this using macro identifier concatenation and external variables, but I can’t define a global variable from inside a function (using `extern` would result in a declaration rather than a definition, and a definition in a function is by default in local scope), so I end up with something that works only in the same scope (or stopping from an inner scope would work, but not the other way).

How could I do something alike? for example how to define (for example using some complex macro trick, a gcc extension (though I’d prefer to stay standard if possible, but wouldn’t bother too much if a such feature required gcc), or whatever?) a global, preferably multi-file, namespace-unique, made-up variable, for storing the pthread id?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include "misc.c"

const short kHighPriority = 255;
const short kLowPriority = 0;
const short kDefaultTaskPriority = 7;

/* void startTask(void TaskID, 
                  short nTaskPriority = kDefaultTaskPriority) */

pthread_t
startTask (task (*TaskID)(void*), short nTaskPriority)
{
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_t thread;
  struct sched_param param;
  const int policy = sched_getscheduler(0),
    sched_high_prio = sched_get_priority_max(policy), // 19,
    sched_low_prio = sched_get_priority_min(policy), // -20,
    sched_range_prio = sched_high_prio - sched_low_prio;
  pthread_attr_init (&attr);
  pthread_attr_getinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED);
  pthread_attr_getschedparam (&attr, &param);
  param.sched_priority = -(((nTaskPriority
                             - kLowPriority) * sched_range_prio
                            / kHighPriority) + sched_low_prio);
  pthread_attr_setschedparam (&attr, &param);
  pthread_create (&thread, &attr, (void*) TaskID, NULL);
  return thread;
}

void
stopTask (pthread_t thread)
{
  pthread_cancel(thread);
}

void
stopAllTasks ()
{
  exit(0);
}

#define startTask(task, priority) \
  static pthread_t task##_thread = startTask(task, priority)
#define stopTask(task) \
  stopTask(task##_thread)
```

I’d prefer, ideally, to solve this problem without external (that is, non-standard) libraries, at compile time, with C instead of C++, standard (C11 doesn’t disturb me) if possible, in this order (`!`gcc-specific `||` `!` cxx `||` compile-time `||` stdc).

That is, except if something else is found, I’m okay with C++, even more with GNU extensions and totally okay with C/C++11 to solve this problem at compile-time instead of runtime, for instance (though my reimplementation seems mostly standard to me, global-scope multithreading requiring GNU doesn’t seems too much).

Comment: Seems like trouble if you ever want multiple copies of the same thread function running at the same time.

Comment: let's say it’s either not supported, or only one or all are stopped when you `stopTask`, since the API specify this way.

Comment: robotc’s api is made for programming beginners, making interface higher level at the expense of powerfulness, consistence and control makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). A dictionary associates keys with values. The key is this case would by the task name, converted to a string. And the value would be the thread ID from `pthread_create`.

The dictionary itself could be implemented any way you like: hash table, binary tree, linked list, or even an array. The dictionary interface consists of three functions: Add(), Find(), and Remove().

To use the dictionary, the `startTask` and `stopTask` macros convert the function name to a string using the `#` operator. The string is then passed to the `StartTask` and `StopTask` functions and used as the `key` in the dictionary.

Here's some sample code that demonstrates the concepts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define startTask(task, priority) startTask(#task, task, priority)
#define stopTask(task) stopTask(#task)

void dictionaryAdd(char *key, pthread_t threadID)
{
    printf("Adding key: %s\n", key);
    // add the key with its associated threadID to the dictionary
}

bool dictionaryFind(char *key, pthread_t *threadID)
{
    printf("Finding key: %s\n", key);
    // find the key in the dictionary and get the associated threadID
    *threadID = 0;
    return true;
}

void dictionaryRemove(char *key)
{
    // remove the key and associated value from the dictionary
    printf("Removing key: %s\n", key);
}

void startTask(char *name, ...)
{
    pthread_t threadID = 0;
    pthread_create(&threadID, ...);
    dictionaryAdd(name, threadID);
}

void stopTask(char *name)
{
    pthread_t threadID;
    if (dictionaryFind(name, &threadID))
    {
        pthread_cancel(threadID);
        dictionaryRemove(name);
    }
}

void *foo(void *arg)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    startTask(foo, 10);
    stopTask(foo);
}
```

The output from the code:

```
Adding key: foo
Finding key: foo
Removing key: foo
```

Comment: I thought to it, though in my mind I formulated it as “associative array” and “hashtable”, but an hashtable being a bit huge and complex to reimplement a nth time in C…  I don’t want to introduce a dependency to any external (ie non-standard) library.

Comment: Actually the main reason this solution disturbs me is that it solves the problem at run-time rather than compile time (that’s why I essentially used macros and tagged this question as such). And this appears to me as a fairly excessive amount of runtime complexification for what is otherwise mainly a question of scope…

Comment: @galex-713 I suppose I should have started my answer with an explanation of why I don't think you can do this at compile time (the macros need to be in function scope and global scope at the same time). But I've found that any time I say it can't be done, someone has to prove me wrong, even if it's in the most horribly useless way possible. So there, I just helped you out by saying it can't be done.

Comment: As for the complexity, I would just use simple arrays. One array of `char *` to hold the `key`. Another array to hold the thread IDs. Initialize the `key` array with `NULL`. To **add**, find a `NULL`, and replace it with the key (put the value at the same index in the other array). To **remove**, set the `key` back to `NULL`. To **find**, do a `strcmp` with the non-NULL entries in the key array.

Comment: I’d have liked a suck explanation indeed: wouldn’t there a macro way (maybe not possible within the limitations of cpp) to make `task_##thread` simply global (as `extern` in C doesn’ work since it’s only for declaration, not definition, and there’s no other keyword for making global (at best `static` would preserve its scope between function calls), and I guess C doesn’t allow declaring + defining a global variable from inside a function… and since macros don’t allow to put redefinitions of macros in them so to do that later, outside of function scope…). Maybe it’s just not possible with cpp?

Comment: Simple array (not speaking of the potential need to `realloc`, if it’s fully done at run-time, though you could use a cpp-incremented counter to define its size from macros like `startTask`, like `__COUNTER__`, but since there’s only one its use may be broken by other use by the user), would be less complexity at compile time at the expense of even more complexity at run-time on the long go.

Comment: finally, maybe you’re right: it should be possible to do it purely with macros, yet with cpp + C it’s evidently not, I’m not resigned, and an hashtable would introduce more complexity, but if it stays optional, it might be ok and still stay of negligible overhead next to thread running and I/O… and that would be okay according my standards using C++, as I guess C++ probably has some kind of standard default implementation of hashtables.

Comment: I’ll probably end researching that, as I can solve many other compatibility details by turning on C++… Yet if you (or anyone) update your question to work using only C++ standard libraries, thus without having to redefine functions for associative arrays, I will accept your answer right-away.